# How to import specific version of Tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to integrate the TensorFlow library into my IDE so I can train with it.

I went to this site: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup and it looks like I got the latest and greatest version:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>`

However, that version is not working for because of how it outputs the `tf` object in my code editor.

I am looking for something close to this version:

[image]

But as you can see, it's confusing to me, which one of these is it exactly? When I pull up the `versions` property in my console I just see `1.0.0` across the board, so I am not sure what version I am looking for, but it's whatever outputs what you see above or close to it.

The important thing is I write out in my IDE:

```
const data = tf.tensor([1,2,3]);
const otherData = tf.tensor([4,5,6]);

data.add(otherData);
```

I should see this:
`[5, 7, 9]` outputted, instead I see this:

```
{"isDisposedInternal":false,"shape":[3],"dtype":"float32","size":3,"strides":[],"dataId":{},"id":267,"rankType":"1"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for tensor.print().

If you really need to change the version, just change it in the src attribute of the script tag.

Comment: Sebastian, I tried `tf.tensor.print(data.add(otherData));` and that did not work for me.  I also tried it this way `tf.Print(data.add(otherData))`. How exactly do you use it?

Comment: I also tried it this way `tensor.print(data.add(otherData))`

Comment: You have to use data.print() and data.add(otherData).print()

Comment: yeah, this `data.add(otherData).print();` prints nothing to my IDE.

Comment: It prints it to the standard output.